# Prove: $U \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}(U, Y)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

Rewording this problem via what Zhen Lin's notion of the original question is.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be ringed spaces.  Prove that, for each open $U \subset X$, the presheaf $$U \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}(U, Y)$$ is a sheaf.

Is this because we can always get a presheaf (in fact, a sheaf) on any topological space $X$ by fixing some topological space $Y$ and sending any open subset $U$ of $X$ to the set of continuous functions from $U$ to $Y$ with the obvious restriction maps?

How would I go about proving this?

Comment: The question is asking you to show that the presheaf $U \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}(U, Y)$ is a sheaf, nothing more.

Comment: I agree with Zhen: You're being asked to formalize the notion that morphisms glue (uniquely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're just asked to show that if you have continuous functions $f_i$ on $U_i$ agreeing on $U_i\cap U_j$ then they extend to a unique continuous function $f$ on $\cup U_i$, which is true because continuous functions are defined pointwise and continuity is local.

**Edit:** You also need to show that the homomorphisms $f_i^\#:\mathcal{O}_Y\to(f_i)_*\mathcal{O}_X|_{U_i}$ glue. But since for some $\sigma\in\mathcal{O}_Y(V)$ $f_i^\#\sigma$ and $f_j^\#\sigma$ agree on the common pushforward $(f_i)_*\mathcal O_X|_{U_i\cap U_j}=(f_j)_*\mathcal O_X|_{U_i\cap U_j}$, we have a coherent system of sections of $\mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(V))$ over the cover $f^{-1}(V)\cap U_i$ which glue uniquely to $f^\#\sigma\in f_*\mathcal{O}_X(V)$.

Comment: Actually, $X$ and $Y$ are ringed spaces, so one has to do a little bit more than that.

Comment: Yes-looking at the history, only the first and third edits mention we want ringed spaces, so I guessed at the intention in my answer.